# SQL Counting Total Time but resetting total if large gap

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table containing device movements.

```
MoveID DeviceID Start End
```

I want to find out if there is a way to sum up the total movement days for each device to the present. However if there is a gap 6 weeks bewtween an end date and the next start date then the time count is reset.

```
MoveID    DeviceID    Start     End
1           1         2011-1-1  2011-2-1
2           1         2011-9-1  2011-9-20
3           1         2011-9-25 2011-9-28
```

The total for device should be 24 days as because there is a gap of greater than 6 weeks. Also I'd like to find out the number of days since the first movement in the group in this case 28 days as the latest count group started on the 2011-9-1

I thought I could do it with a stored proc and a cursor etc (which is not good) just wondered if there was anything better?

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Times TABLE
(
    MoveID INT,
    DeviceID INT,
    Start DATETIME,
    [End] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Times VALUES (1, 1, '1/1/2011', '2/1/2011')
INSERT INTO @Times VALUES (2, 1, '9/1/2011', '9/20/2011')
INSERT INTO @Times VALUES (3, 1, '9/25/2011', '9/28/2011')

INSERT INTO @Times VALUES (4, 2, '1/1/2011', '2/1/2011')
INSERT INTO @Times VALUES (5, 2, '3/1/2011', '4/20/2011')
INSERT INTO @Times VALUES (6, 2, '5/1/2011', '6/20/2011')

DECLARE @MaxGapInWeeks INT
SET @MaxGapInWeeks = 6

SELECT
    validTimes.DeviceID,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, validTimes.Start, validTimes.[End]) + 1) AS TotalDays,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(validTimes.Start), MAX(validTimes.[End])) + 1 AS TotalDaysInGroup
FROM 
    @Times validTimes LEFT JOIN
    @Times timeGap 
        ON timeGap.DeviceID = validTimes.DeviceID
        AND timeGap.MoveID <> validTimes.MoveID
        AND DATEDIFF(WEEK, validTimes.[End], timeGap.Start) > @MaxGapInWeeks
WHERE timeGap.MoveID IS NULL
GROUP BY validTimes.DeviceID
```

Comment: Just wondering how to obtain total days since start of period column. E.g. for DeviceID one it should be 28 days. Since new period started on 2011-9-1

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that last part... I've updated the script to include that.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer. Flexibility of the MaxGapInWeeks  variable, using my example end column name and additional test answer, and use of table variable rather than temp table. Really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #test
(
MoveID int,
DeviceID int,
Start date,
End_time date
)
--drop table #test
insert into #test values
(1,1,'2011-1-1','2011-2-1'),
(2,1,'2011-9-1','2011-9-20'),
(3,1,'2011-9-25','2011-9-28')

select 
   a.DeviceID, 
   sum(case when datediff(dd, a.End_time, isnull(b.Start, a.end_time)) > 42 /*6 weeks = 42 days*/ then 0 else datediff(dd,a.Start, a.End_time)+1 /*we will count also the last day*/ end) as movement_days,
```

sum(case when datediff(dd, a.End_time, isnull(b.Start, a.end_time)) > 42 /*6 weeks = 42 days*/ then 0 else datediff(dd,a.Start, a.End_time)+1 /*we will count also the last day*/ end  + case when b.MoveID is null then datediff(dd, a.Start, a.End_time) + 1 else 0 end) as total_days
    from 
       #test a 
       left join #test b 
          on a.DeviceID = b.DeviceID 
             and a.MoveID + 1 = b.MoveID 
    group by 
       a.DeviceID

Let me know if you need some explanation - there can be more ways to do that...

Comment: That works perfectly to get the total days as far as I can see :). Is there anyway to get the number of days since the first date in the current period for each device?

Comment: This looks as though it relies on `MoveID` being sequential within each `DeviceID`. Is that the case?

Comment: Should be but I wouldn't want to rely on that. It's possible users have gone back and changed dates etc.

Comment: I have added also the 28 days calc to that

Comment: Really appreciate the answer and the help. You were the first so maybe should have accepted your answer. Not sure what etiquette is on accepting answers doesn't seem to be in the FAQ.

Comment: You can still upvote his answer if it was helpful, but not the accepted answer.